# .Convert String into a 2Bytearray(U32)- python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a string `text="0000001011001100"`
I want to convert this string into a 2 byte array something like this **(b'\x00\x02')**

```
byte_array=(socket.htons(text)).to_bytes(2,sys.byteorder)
```

But this is not working and giving an error that **int** required
I have converted the text to **int** but then the entire string changes

I need help on this

Comment: What you mean by *2 byte array*?

Comment: @Kasramvd 2byte array means U32 
Sorry if I used a wrong term actually I am a beginner in pyhton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert text to integer and then you can use `struct` module

```
import struct

text = "0000001011001100"
number = int(text, 2) # 716

result = struct.pack("h", number)

b'\xcc\x02'

# or with > to change bytes order

result = struct.pack(">h", number)

b'\x02\xcc'
```

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the binary representation into an int **with base 2**

```
text="0000001011001100"
num =int(text,2) #interprets string in base 2
result = chr(num) #is this what you want?
```

if you are using python 3.x and want to convert the text into a `bytes` object from a string of any length by splitting up each 8 characters:

```
bytes(int(text[i:i+8],2) for i in range(0,len(text),8))
```

but for your example it gives `b'\x02\xcc'` so it is possible you want something different